# Declaring and assigning a value to a variable

Tags: vba, variables, excel, syntax, variable-assignment

This morning I decided to open my book of stupid questions and found one question I can't get out of my head (might be that the question should be on code review, but you tell me).

So here it goes - now in VBA you normally would declare a variable and assign a value to it by what I would use as standard like this:

```
Dim n as Integer
n = 1
```

Or with objects using Set:

```
Dim wb as Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveSheet
```

But there is also an other syntax possibility here that allows you to both declare and assign a value at the same line by doing this (lets call this alternative way):

```
Dim n as Integer: n = 1
Dim wb as Worksheet: Set wb = ActiveSheet
```

Now we have two ways to declare and assign a variable. What my book of stupid doesn't tell is is there some reason or case where the alternative way will not work or why it's almost never used? To my head if variable is at the beginning of a program given a value, it would be easier to read the code syntax using alternative syntax.

O please wise and mighty SO members, enlighten me please - when would I use or should I use the alternative way at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually no difference; the ":" is just a line separator, formatting if you will - not a convention specific to variable declaration:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx

In some cases, using it makes the code more readable, but clearly it also has the potential to confuse :)

Comment: + 1 `not a convention specific to variable declaration` True :)

Comment: Seems quite explicit. Tough I came up with a sub question - what about when it's in a statement like this `rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll`? Would it be allowed to write this `rng.PasteSpecial Paste` and on next line `=xlPasteAll`?

Comment: No, `:=` assigns an expected **named argument** parameter - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548723/what-does-a-colon-equals-in-vb-net-do

Comment: Thanks @Tim yo tha besssss! ;)